# Finding distribution of $\frac{X^2}{Y}$ given joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

So I have the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$:
\begin{align}
f(x,y) = cx, \ 0 < x^2 < y < \sqrt{x} < 1
\end{align}
and I want to find the distribution of $X^2/Y$. So I set $U = X^2/Y$ and introduced the auxiliary variable $V = Y$. The inverse yields

\begin{align}
&U = \frac{X^2}{Y} \implies X = \sqrt{UV} \\
&V = Y \implies Y = V
\end{align}

It is obvious that $0 < u < 1$, but I am struggling to specify the domain of $V$. So my question is, how can I specify the limits of $V$ here?

Comment: Hint: **Draw** a sketch of the unit square and indicate on it _which_ points $(x,y)$ in the interior satisfy $0 < x^2 < y < \sqrt{x}$. Pick _one_ point in this region (say $(x.y) = (0.25, 0.4)$) and figure out the answer for this point. Repeat for other points till you see a pattern emerge upon looking at all the calculations.

Comment: Sketching the support of $f$ is simplified by recognizing it is the intersection of $0\lt x^2 \lt y \lt 1$ and $0 \lt y^2 \lt x \lt 1,$ which are symmetrically situated about the diagonal.  Thus, all you need to do is plot the graph of $y=x^2,$ reflect that about the diagonal $x=y,$ and shade in the region bounded by those two graphs.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I don't really see how this will help me defining the limits of V in terms of U. Kindly provide more hints.